# Why npx mix --production creates numbered files with same name and same directory?

Tags: laravel, webpack, webpack-mix

Hi I try to run my npx mix --production command and I  have an issue  with that. App build but I found that on output it generated lot of files inside js/app/ folder with numbers as name. What is it ? How can I avoid that?

```
                                       
js/app/1633.js │ 16.5 KiB  │     

js/app/1562.js │ 16.6 KiB  │       
....                                      
js/app/XXXX.js │ 16.5 KiB  │
```

There are at least 20 files inside that app/ folder and it´s minified js but I not specify anywhere to do that.
I already have my /js/app.js file in my output:

```
/js/app.js | 818 KiB
```

Here is my webpack.mix.js:

```
// Javascript
const javascriptInputsToCompile = [
    'app.js',
    'libs/prism.js',
     ...
    'utils/validation.js',
];
javascriptInputsToCompile.forEach((file) => {
    mix.js(`resources/assets/js/${file}`, `js/${file}`);
});
```

thx for any advice/help :)

Comment: What you see i a version pattern. It is very useful to ensure after a deplyoment that the css and js files are not loaded from the cache of the respective client.

Answer (score 0):

What you see i a version pattern. It is very useful to ensure after a deployment that the css and js files are not loaded from the cache of the respective client.

Define an additional configuration with the entries that are not to be versioned in. Do a search in your IDE for `enableVersioning`. You should then comment out the line `enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())`. Then add these to your module.exports.